# CFLAGS and gcc at configure not passed in makefile

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to compile python 32 bit on OSX. In order to do so, I want to specify -m32, so I dutifully specified

```
CFLAGS='-m32' LDFLAGS='-m32' ./configure
```

The configure executes correctly, but when I invoke make, the gcc execution has no trace of the -m32 flag. In order to have it, I had to do a more aggressive approach:

```
CFLAGS='-m32' LDFLAGS='-m32' CC='gcc -m32' ./configure
```

I don't really understand why the CFLAGS I specify are not passed (the LDFLAGS are. I find LDFLAG=-m32 in the Makefile). Is it an error of the configure script, or am I doing this wrong ?

I'm using python 2.6.0 (don't ask)

Comment: I'm using "Python 3.2.1 bzipped source tarball" on Linux and it works for me (tm).

Comment: Which version of Python is this? Your first example works fine for me with 2.7.2, 2.6.7 & 3.1.4. What shell are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer then as well. It seems that this a bug in this version, which was fixed later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I can reproduce that with Python-2.6. That seems to be a bug in that version, and is fixed in a newer one.

Still, I can tell you that it is common for various packages to override or filter `CFLAGS` of values considered unsafe and so on. This often covers `-m32` as well.

Moreover, many packages simply ignore `LDFLAGS` (which is an error indeed). Thus, for the particular case of building 32-bit package versions, it is common to override `CC` like you did and leave `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` alone.